# Get raw text from lxml element?

Tags: python, selenium, lxml

I have a good python code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("some_url")
raw_educations = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='education']/div/div/div")
educations = raw_educations[0].text.split("\n")
```

**raw_educations[0]** is this line

```
<div class="ds dt" id="u_0_2"><div class="cm du"><a class="co" href="/Harvard/"><img src="https://scontent.fhel6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/p48x48/38977734_905688203096487_2026691898_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&amp;ccb=2&amp;_nc_sid=dbb9e7&amp;efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&amp;_nc_ohc=j6Sj9DTpNBIAX9LLfur&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fhel6-1.fna&amp;tp=3&amp;oh=c33ee8200b4e553ea92ca2edca2f4165&amp;oe=5FE9E69D" class="dv dw cb r" alt="Harvard University, profile picture"/></a><div class="dx cp"><div class="ee"><div><span class="dy dz de ea"><a class="cq" href="/Harvard/">Harvard University</a></span></div></div><div><span class="eb cs"><span class="ef ck cl">Computer Science and Psychology</span></span></div><div><span class="eb ec">30 August 2002 - 30 April 2004</span></div></div><div class="cr"/></div></div>
```

**educations** is this line

```
['Harvard University', 'Computer Science and Psychology', '30 August 2002 - 30 April 2004']
```

I want to write similar code with lxml library

**My code**

```
from lxml import etree

file_path = "Mark.html"
with open(file_path) as html_file:
    html = html_file.read()
    # print(html) # prints correct html
    htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(file_path, htmlparser)
    educations = tree.xpath("//div[@id='education']/div/div/div")
    print(etree.tostring(educations[0])) # Prints raw_educations[0], but i want educations
```

The code prints raw_educations[0], but i want educations
***What should I change in my code?***

Mark.html code is here https://pastebin.com/BJbgXtg0

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should be sorted out by conforming the end of your lxml `for` loop to the one you have for selenium. That is, change

```
print(etree.tostring(educations[0]))
```

to

```
print(educations[0].text.split("\n"))
```

Edit - to:

```
educations[0].xpath('.//span//text()')
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work, because educations[0].text is None